# How to call Springs service method from controller (Junit)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, mockito, spring-test, springmockito

I have seen [example](http://www.luckyryan.com/2013/08/24/unit-test-controllers-spring-mvc-test/) , how to call spring controller using mockito.

Using Mock I call Spring MVC controller.
Controller Invokes Spring service class.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml" })
public class TestController {


    @Mock
    private TestService testService;

    @InjectMocks
    private PaymentTransactionController paymentController;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;


     @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        this.setMockMvc(MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(paymentController).build());
    }

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc.perform(post("/tr/test").content(...)).andExpect(status().isOk());
        // testService.save(); <-- another way
    }
```

Ok it works well. I calls my Spring controller very well. But In Spring controller I have Injected Service Layer.

```
@Autowired
private TestService serviceTest;


@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody()
public String test(HttpServletRequest request) {
   ...
    serviceTest.save(); 
   // in save method I call dao and dao perist data;
   // I have injected dao intrface in serviceTest layer
   ...
   return result;

}
```

The problem is that, my app does not invokes save method, it is not entered in it. I have no error too. The same result is when I call save() method from Junit (I have commented it in test() method).

When I debug, I have seen that interrupt method happens  of org.mockito.internal.creation.MethodInterceptorFilter

How to solve this problem? what happens?

Comment: Can't understand your question. **You** are **mocking** the service. It is normal that nothing is called, you have just to *verify* what was called ...

Comment: I want to call service layer in order to to then check if it was written well. does not it?

Comment: I have MockMVC because of I did not wanted to started Tomcat Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just change @InjectMocks to @Autowired. This fix the issue! In this case you are not mocking, you are invoking method with real data.

Answer (score 2):

If you are doing a unit test of your controller, you should mock the service layer (what you are doing). In this kind of test, you just control that :

- the correct methods of the controller are triggered and they produce what is expected
- the correct methods in service layer are called ... **in the mock**

You simply have to configure the return values of the methods of the  mock (if relevant), or control what was called

```
@Before
public void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    this.setMockMvc(MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(paymentController).build());
    // set return values from the mocked service
    when(testService.find(1)).thenReturn(...);
}
```

and verify later what has been called

```
@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    this.mockMvc.perform(post("/tr/test").content(...)).andExpect(status().isOk());
    // testService.save(); <-- another way
    verify(testService, times(1)).save();
}
```

If you want to do an *integration test*, you do not mock the service, but setup an application context to inject real beans, but ordinarily use an embedded database instead of the real one.

Comment: I understand, I configure the return value. But I do not understand the main purpose of when should I use mock. If I configure return value, when benefit does it have?

Comment: It is how **unit** test work : you test only one class using *mocks* for all the other objects with which it has interactions. The mocks are dumb objects for which you configure the output when given input. That way you cannot fail a test in a class because of a problem in another class.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you perform post to "/tr/test" resource, but request mapping in your controller is '/payment'. Make sure you post to resource mapped in the controller.